# How to move a div horizontal then vertical using css animation?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to move a div horizontal then vertical using css animation as shown in the following picture.
The black arrow lines indicate the way i want move the green box. But box after moving horizontally it moves diagonally as show by the blue arrow instead of moving vertically show by the vertical downward arrow.

[image]

```
.mybox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lawngreen;
}

.myanimation{
    -webkit-animation: simple 3s forwards ease;
}

@-webkit-keyframes simple {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(300px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(300px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(300px);
    -o-transform: translateX(300px);
    transform: translateX(300px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(300px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(300px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(300px);
    -o-transform: translateY(300px);
    transform: translateY(300px);
  }
}
```

[Here is the plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/TBlElKGRefpf4Cf9OGuw?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its becuase you havent specified a `100%` end point for the `x` transform, so it is reverting after being set at `50%`

```js
(function(){
    var myBox = $(".mybox");
    $("#movebtn").on("click",function(){
        myBox.addClass("myanimation");
    })
})();
```

```css
.mybox {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lawngreen;
}

.myanimation{
    -webkit-animation: simple 3s forwards ease;
}

@-webkit-keyframes simple {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(300px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(300px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(300px);
    -o-transform: translateX(300px);
    transform: translateX(300px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(300px) translateY(300px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(300px) translateY(300px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(300px) translateY(300px);
    -o-transform: translateX(300px) translateY(300px);
    transform: translateX(300px) translateY(300px);
    
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mybox"></div>
     <br>
     <button id="movebtn">Move</button>
     <script data-require="jquery@2.1.1" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can safely remove `-moz-` and `-o-` prefixes for [`transform`](http://caniuse.com/#search=transforms) and add `animation: simple 3s forwards ease` for non-prefix browsers.

Comment: It bit confusing for me . If i would ask you to move the box in square  shape >>> horizontal 300px to right then vertical downward then horizontal leftward then vertical upward then what is the best way to do it.