# TSQL replacing empty fields with data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has a layout like this

```
1 2 3 4 5

1 1 1 1 

2 2 2 2
```

The last column in the second and third row have been left blank. They should contain a string. So I wrote this SQL to insert into the table

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (5) VALUES ('This is the string');
```

But this left me with

```
1 2 3 4 5

1 1 1 1 

2 2 2 2 

NULL NULL NULL NULL This is the string
```

Which obviously wasn't my intention. How can I fix this?

Comment: You should read a SQL tutorial. Look for one mentioning the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: So update is what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `UPDATE` to change existing rows:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab([1] INT, [2] INT, [3] INT , [4] INT, [5] VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #tab([1],[2],[3],[4]) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1),(2 ,2, 2, 2);

UPDATE #tab
SET [5] = 'This is the string'
WHERE [5] = '' OR [5] IS NULL;

SELECT *
FROM #tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/386698)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Give this a whirl...

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET 5 = 'This is a string'
WHERE COALESCE(5, '') = ''   -- only update where 5 is currently NULL or blank, i.e. ''
```

INSERT - Add new rows to an table

UPDATE - Change the values of existing rows in a table

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  It's the answer to the question based on the second sentence.

Comment: Check my edit. You include tag and then appear the run code button. That work for jscript not for sql code

Comment: btw great use of `COALESCE` but you need put the `5` between bracket `[5]`

Comment: The intent was just to display the code, and the 5 was inferred from the question as the fifth column name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27377202/3470178 this answer make sense becasue is a script and you can see it work. But for sql code doesnt do anything beside show the code. Maybe you want is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/da1d1/1